# Generalized forces for virtual work - Why did they drop the summation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, notation, textbook-erratum

I am going through a PDF by Subhankar Ray & J. Shamanna  on virtual work [here](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-physics0410123/page/n5/mode/2up) and according to the PDF, equation 29, they write gerneralized force as:

1. $$Q_j = -\nabla_k\tilde{V}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}\right) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}\tag{29}$$

But shouldn't it be:

2. $$Q_j = -\sum^N_{k=1}\nabla_k\tilde{V}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\textbf{r}_k}{\partial q_j}\right) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}~?$$

And according to [Goldstein](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs667/2005sp/readings/goldsteinCh1.pdf), page 22, just above eq(1.54), they also don't drop the summation.

Why did they drop the summation in (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either a typo or that eq. (29) uses [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).